# How to pass value to using external variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

following code works properly

```
draw([['Rice',20,28,38],['Paddy',31,38,55],]);
```

but when i try using external variable like

```
var val1=20;
var val2=30;
var val3=40;
draw([['Rice',val1,val2,val3],['Paddy',31,38,55],]);
```

It wont work.

Comment: *"It wont work."* is not an error description.

Comment: Surely you can give more details other than "it won't work"?

Comment: The two pieces of code should work in exactly the same way. Is this a reduced test case that has reduced the code so much that the problem has gone away?

Comment: Thanks guys i am getting a blank screen when i run the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just showing that your example code works fine using the Firebug console. Can you post more of your code? Your stripped-down example is probably missing something else that's causing a problem.

What is your `draw()` function doing? Could something in that function be breaking?

EDIT: Another problem could be the trailing comma after your second array. That will throw an error in Internet Explorer.

```
alert([['Rice',val1,val2,val3],['Paddy',31,38,55],]);
```

should be:

```
alert([['Rice',val1,val2,val3],['Paddy',31,38,55]]);
```

That may solve your issue (though you also have that in your 'working' example, but I thought it worth mentioning).

[image: Just showing that your example code works fine.]

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippets are not equivalent -- the second one has different values (`['Rice',20,30,40]` vs `['Rice',20,28,38]`). Other than that, they are equivalent and should have the same effects.